# How to add class to all TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jQuery with addClass to add class to some elements.
But for some reason not all "td" get the class assigned (the ones with the .currentmonth).

```
$("td").addClass("aaawwwasdsad");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wheelq/7Lesommm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because other Javascript functions run later.

Look : https://jsfiddle.net/p9kogsmL/14/

Define it into the end of calendar function :

```
     ...

        document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML += calendarTable;
        $("td").addClass("aaawwwasdsad");
      }
```

Comment: Indeed, one second too late here :)

Comment: I would add it to the end of go12() function so it runs just once after all the TDs are added in the DOM.

Comment: I thought so, but had no idea how to figure this out. Could you please tell me how did you check that these "td"'s got generated later?

Comment: @meso_2600 Because it is the calendar function that generates <td> additional thanks to an eventListener. They are thus generated after the code of the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a class to all td ,you have to use `each` loop.
here is an example:

```
$("td").each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("aaawwwasdsad");
});
```